# Annotations lost when making PdfPage to Image with iText7

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, itext, itext7

Annotations are lost when I convert a page into an image object.

What I am trying to do is to convert the page into an image so that I can resize it, rotate it if nessecary and center it on a page on a new document. This is to make space for a header and footer.

The code I use for converting it into an image looks like this:

```
public static final Image convertPageToImage(PdfDocument src, int pageNumber, PdfDocument dest) throws IOException, BadPasswordException {

    PdfPage page = src.getPage(pageNumber);
    PdfFormXObject copy = page.copyAsFormXObject(dest);
    return new Image(copy);
}
```

The PDF pages I convert to images are meant to represent images but just using actual graphics is not an option... sadly.

I already searched for a method to "flatten" the annotations onto the page so they don't go lost. But with iText7 only flattening of form fields is possible. I also found a line of code that looks like this:

```
pdfDocument.getCatalog().getOCGProperties(true).remove(PdfName.OCProperties);
```

but that also doesnt work.

Best idea I found so far is manually flattening the annotations by extracting some appearance stream and wrapping that arround a FormXObject so that that can be put onto a Canvas. But my knowledge of the PDF specification is just not enough.

Can someone help me?

Comment: *"what I am trying to do is to convert the page into an image so that I can resize it, rotate it if nessecary and center it on a page on a new document. this is to make space for a header and footer."* - Except for arbitrary rotations (i.e. by angles other than multiples of 90°) it is easier to do so without transformation into an "image" by simply editing the page entries. Would you be interested in an answer to that effect?

Comment: There is also the "resizing and center on a page of a new document"-part. If you know a solution that can cover all that without converting the source page into an image I would like to hear it.

Comment: As can be understood from ISO 32000, annotations aren't part of Form XObjects, so the behavior you are experiencing is normal.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie is there a way to somehow make them part of the page?
so that they are not longer annotations but basically graphics printed on the page.